# Can I move attributes of temporary objects in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, temporary-objects

I'm writing an iterator that depends on items in a vector and an iterator-factory that spawns said iterators. The code is conceptually equal to the following:

```c++
struct Iter
{
  int i = 0;
  vector<int> vec;

  Iter(const vector<int>& _vec):
    vec(_vec)
  {
    cout << "copied vector of size "<<vec.size()<<" for iterator\n";
  }

  Iter(vector<int>&& _vec):
    vec(move(_vec))
  {
    cout << "moved vector of size "<<vec.size()<<" for iterator\n";
  }

  int& operator*() { return vec[i]; }
  Iter& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
  bool operator!=(const Iter& _it) const { return false; }
};

struct Factory
{
  vector<int> fac_vec;

  Factory(const vector<int>& _v):
    fac_vec(_v)
  {
    cout << "copied vector of size " << fac_vec.size() << " for factory\n";
  }

  Factory(vector<int>&& _v):
    fac_vec(move(_v))
  {
    cout << "moved vector of size "<<fac_vec.size()<<" for factory\n";
  }

  Iter begin() { return Iter(fac_vec); }
  Iter end() { return Iter({}); }
};
```

```c++
int main(){
  for(const int i: Factory({1,2,3}))
    cout << i << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Now, running this code gives me (g++ 8.3):

```
moved vector of size 3 for factory   [ initialization of the factory with {1,2,3} - moved ]
copied vector of size 3 for iterator [ initialization of the begin-iterator with fac_vec - copied ]
moved vector of size 0 for iterator  [ initialization of the end-iterator with {} - moved ]
```

This is kind of disappointing as I was hoping that the last `begin()` would call `Iter`'s move-constructor since the factory is being destroyed right after (isn't it?) and the compiler has all the information it needs to decide this.

I figure I could do what I want using `std::shared_ptr` but this incurs overhead both in the code and in the program. I'd much rather tell the compiler to *move* `fac_vec` when the last `begin()` is called. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think the Factory object is destroyed after begin() is called. It persists until the for() loop is finished.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, the vector `fac_vec` is never touched again after the `begin()`. It can savely be moved, so I think the compiler should be able to move it, I just don't know how to tell it to.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I think you'd need to use std::move(fac_vec) in the call to Iter() constructor (the answer below seems to go into much more detail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when implementing iterators, you take the vector's iterator or a reference to the vector:

```
struct Iter
{
  int i = 0;
  vector<int>* vec;

  Iter(vector<int>& _vec):
    vec(&_vec)
  {
    cout << "copied vector of size "<<vec->size()<<" for iterator\n";
  }

  int& operator*() { return (*vec)[i]; }
  Iter& operator++() { ++i; return *this; }
  bool operator!=(const Iter& _it) const { return false; }
};
```

That way you never copy.

Better, use vector's own iterator:

```
struct Iter
{
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  Iter(vector<int>::iterator _it):
    it(_it)
  { }

  int& operator*() { return *it; }
  Iter& operator++() { ++it; return *this; }
  bool operator!=(const Iter& _it) const { return false; }
};
```

But then, you can drop `Iter` and simply use the vector iterators:

```
struct Factory
{
  // ...    

  auto begin() { return fac_vec.begin(); }
  auto end() { return fac_vec.end(); }
};
```

---

Now if you truely want to contain a value inside the iterator **(not recommended)**.

The compiler won't move `fac_vec` since it's a lvalue to a vector. No move here. You need an rvalue to a vector to move it.

You can get that by overloading the function for rvalue reference instance:

```
struct Factory
{
  vector<int> fac_vec;

  Factory(const vector<int>& _v):
    fac_vec(_v)
  {
    cout << "copied vector of size " << fac_vec.size() << " for factory\n";
  }

  Factory(vector<int>&& _v):
    fac_vec(move(_v))
  {
    cout << "moved vector of size "<<fac_vec.size()<<" for factory\n";
  }

  // moving  when Factory is temporary
  Iter begin() && { return Iter(std::move(fac_vec)); }
  Iter end() && { return Iter({}); }

  // copying
  Iter begin() const& { return Iter(fac_vec); }
  Iter end() const& { return Iter({}); }
};
```

But the for loop won't call the move version. Why? It would be dangerous, since that would require calling move multiple times on a type.

A range for is roughly equivalent to that:

```
auto&& range = <range expr>; // forwarding reference to range (rvalue in your case)
auto begin = range.begin(); // range is lvalue, so calls the const&
auto end = range.end(); // range is lvalue, so calls the const&

for (/* ... */) {
    // body
}
```

To use your move operations, it would require to cast the range to rvalue multiple times, potentially using a moved from value:

```
auto begin = std::move(range).begin(); // range is lvalue but moved so calls the &&
auto end = std::move(range).end(); // range is lvalue but moved so calls the &&
```

If you want to use value in iterators which is not recommended, you cannot use range for loop and must use old style for loops.

Keep in mind that calling like this move is oftentimes reguarded as code smell, and using move multiple time is even more so.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation, I was unaware of the "&&"-classification of methods. When I said "conceptually equal" I was simplifying quite a bit. Each iterator will indeed need its own copy of the vector in question.
When you say "`fac_vec` is a lvalue", I do get that I'd have to pump it through `std::move` before to make it into an rvalue, I'm just not sure how to tell g++ to use the moving `begin()` when the Factory is no longer needed.
I tried your code and it still copies the `fac_vec` for me oO

Comment: I see now, good point. However, only one call would ever be an rvalue-call: the last time `begin()` is called (which will, in 99% of the cases be the only time). I guess there is no way to tell the compiler that the last time it calls `begin()` should be an rvalue-call while all others should be lvalue-calls...